# $.ajaxSetup({async:false}) not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

To implement ajax file upload, I am using the following code, which is working fine in Firefox, but fails in IE. I need synchronous operation; for that purpose I used:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
//file upload code in ajax call

for ( i = 0; i < fileCnt; i++ ) {                       
    if ( $('#addFile' + i ).length > 0 ) {
        $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
        $('#addFile'+i).ajaxForm( options );
        $('#addFile'+i).submit();
        console.log( files );
    }
}
```

modified code with setTimeout

```
for(i=0;i<fileCnt;i++){                     
 if ($('#addFile'+i).length > 0) {
                      $('#addFile'+i).ajaxForm(options);
                    $('#addFile'+i).submit();
                    window.setTimeout($('#addFile'+(i+1)).bind($('#addFile'+(i+1))), 0.1);
                    console.log(files);             
                }
            }
```

My console shows file information in Firefox but it's not shown in IE.

Please help me.

Comment: you shouldn't use synchronous requests with ajax. if you think you need to, you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: you need to add **much** more detail

Answer (score 1):

[ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) plugin does file upload using Iframe not ajax.
So using async parameter is useless

Comment: Yah it is using Iframe my requirement is after uploading a file i am trying to get the saved file id into the gloabally declared file[],by using this i performed another action

Answer (score 0):

Using asynchronous: false *really* locks up the UI in IE (and some 
other browsers). In this case, even though you've told it to show the 
image, it's probably not had time to actually do that (browsers 
usually queue these things) before the UI locks because of the 
synchronous call.

The best answer is probably not to use a synchronous call, but rather 
to use an iframe shim or something to make everything on the page 
unclickable while the call is in progress. Synchronous calls lock 
*everything* UI-related in that IE process, not just your page, 
whereas an iframe shim just makes your page unclickable (and provides 
an opportunity for you to show things a bit dimmed-out or something). 
It's also really easy.

```
setTimeout call (directly, or via one of Prototype's useful wrappers 
like Function#defer and Function#delay; Function#defer is just 
Function#delay with a 0.1 delay time)
```

Comment: i implemented setTimeout in the above way i am getting this error            SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'push' 
jquery-1_7.js, line 3008 character 5

Comment: Seems, you're including jQuery twice.